# How do I parse twitter User object returned by the followers call to the api?

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I have tried to find information about the structure of the Twitter object returned by, for example, Tweepy `api.followers`. Upon a cursory look, I thought it was json, but it is not. It starts with `User(follow_request_sent=False, profile_use_background_image=True`. Does anyone have any idea if there's some sort of script or a function in Tweepy that parses this object?

I am using `for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="user").pages():`

and then `ids.extend(page)`, where `id` is just a list. I then do

```
for id in ids:
    print id
```

which I'm not sure is correct. In any case, I'd like to parse every returned `id` offline.

Answer (score 0):

The `api.followers` return list of `User` class instances.

Parsing depend on what data you want. The `User` class provides a different functions. `timeline` `friends` `followers`. You can also use `follow` or `unfollow` functions of the object

Answer (score 0):

To access anything inside the user object

```
User(follow_request_sent=False, .... , location=u'San Francisco, CA', default_profile=False, following=False)
```

use the `.` operator.

For example

```
>>> obj.location
San Francisco, CA
>>> obj.follow_request_sent
False
```